# Displaying a Tooltip for ComboBoxItem - works after moving the mouse, but not on first try

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I'm using WPF ComboBox with only two items in the Combobox. I display the Tooltip for each ComboboxItem by comparing the `item.Content` to a property that one class includes like this :

```
private void OnMouseHover(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var lineSelected = (modelGPZ.GetLineWyList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.isSelected == true));
    ComboBoxItem item = sender as ComboBoxItem;
    if ((double)item.Content == lineSelected.LiniaWyComboBox[0])
    {
        item.ToolTip = "This is the first Item";
    }
    if((double)item.Content == lineSelected.LiniaWyComboBox[1])
    {
        item.ToolTip = "This is the second Item";
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I open the Combobox for the first time I don't get the Tooltip... Strange because the method is called when I debug it. What is more weird, when I hover my mouse over one item, and then another and at last to the first one.. my tooltip shows up..

I tried changing the event to `MouseEnter` which does not even call the method and what I thought so other related events for this such kind of action.
[MSDN ComboBox Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox?view=netframework-4.7.2)

XAML for calling the mentiod method:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseMove"  Handler="OnMouseHover"/>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

For `MouseMove` and `MouseLeave` work as mentioned. For `GotFocus` the problem is `isEditable=True` - focus stayes on the TextBlock unfortunatelly.

**ComboBox in MainWindows.xaml:**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="PRĄD POJEMNOŚCIOWY [A]" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource PRAD_POJEMNOSCIOWY}">
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox x:Name="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox"
              ItemsSource="{Binding LiniaWyComboBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemComboBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              IsEditable="True"
              IsReadOnly="False"
              Text="{Binding Prad_pojemnosciowy, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              PreviewKeyDown="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox_OnPreviewKeyDown">
    <ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="{x:Null}">
         <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding SelectedItemComboBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>

     <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle >
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
       <EventSetter Event="GotFocus"  Handler="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox_GotFocus"/>
      </Style>
     </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ComboBox>
  </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: When you debug step by step, what is the value of item.Content the first time you open the combo? I mean the time it does not work

Comment: The value assinged to ComboboxItem. So it seems it knows what item it is focusing on but.. why isn't it showinh for the first try..

Comment: Have you tried to set a default ToolTip for that element in the constructor? I think it would fix your problem

Comment: It only does that thing when mouse is not over any ComboboxItem it show the content of the ToolTip contructor of MainWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is logically imho. First you have no `ToolTip` for `ComboBoxItem`, on first time `MouseMove` `ToolTip` being set, but it's already too late to trigger it `ToolTip`(it seems `ToolTip` triggered earlier than `MouseMove` for `ComboBoxItem` being fired). So you can see the `ToolTip` only second time you enter the item.

Attach all to the `GotFocus` and it will work as expected:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="GotFocus"  Handler="ComboBoxItem_GotFocus"/>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

private void ComboBoxItem_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var lineSelected = (modelGPZ.GetLineWyList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.isSelected == true));
    ComboBoxItem item = sender as ComboBoxItem;
    if ((double)item.Content == lineSelected.LiniaWyComboBox[0])
    {
        item.ToolTip = "This is the first Item";
    }
    if ((double)item.Content == lineSelected.LiniaWyComboBox[1])
    {
        item.ToolTip = "This is the second Item";
    }
}
```

Better way is to create in ViewModel a property `ItemToolTip` in the object, which is DataContext for the `ComboBoxItem` and bind it:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ToolTip Content="{Binding ItemToolTip}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Example how to prepare data in ViewModel:

```
public List<object> CbxItemsSource { get; set; } = InitCbxSource();
private static List<object> InitCbxSource()
{
    var dblLst = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    return dblLst.Select(dbl => (object)new { ItemValue = dbl, ItemToolTip = "e.g. item index " + dblLst.IndexOf(dbl)}).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I still need some logic for the property to determine what text to choose. Why is it a better way?

Comment: No, you don't need to choose. You prepare the data for `ComboBox.ItemsSource` (where each entry has information about **it's** tool tip text, it is object oriented) and bind them. So you will not need any code behind.

Comment: Yes, I've tried with GotFocus.. doesn't get called unfortunatelly

Comment: How is your ComboBox declared? mine is a DataTemplate in DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate

Comment: I have tested simple in a `StackPanel`. => [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always good! ;)

Comment: The problem is `IsEditable="True"`. Set it to false and it will work.

Comment: Yes. Now it works as intened but.. I'm not able to edit the ComboBox :( Why editing makes this method `GotFocus` go wrong?

Comment: Focus stays on TextBox

Comment: How can I prepare data for `PradPojemnosciowyComboBox.ItemSource` ? These are double values in a list<double> , tooltip should be string I guess

Comment: I have  added an example to my answer.

Comment: sure. This could have helped me but my class that contains the list of double which are binded to the PradPojemnosciowyComboBox are generated in such way: the double values for each object are added to the property list called LiniaWyComboBox(it's an observable collection) and the they are viewed by their index [0] and [1]. I just don't get the feeling with making a new object since my logic breaks because of  `System.InvalidCastException`. Maybe my logic is bad design, but it works as intened. Anyways I need the tooltip **and** the editable ComboBox

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better option to use ToolTipOpening from ComboBox class than OnMouseHover.
Checkout my solution:

```
        <ComboBox>
            <ComboBoxItem ToolTip="" ToolTipOpening="ComboBox_OnToolTipOpening">13.42</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem ToolTip="" ToolTipOpening="ComboBox_OnToolTipOpening">15.82</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

And now code-behind for ToolTip manipulation:

```
        private void ComboBox_OnToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBoxItem item = sender as ComboBoxItem;

            if (item.Content.Equals("13.42"))
            {
                item.ToolTip = "ToolTipItem1";
            }
            else if (item.Content.Equals("15.82"))
            {
                item.ToolTip = "ToolTipItem2";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks fine.. I've added ToolTipOpening to <ComboBox ... /> and no method call on  `ComboBox_OnToolTipOpening`

Comment: You have to add `ToolTip=""` as well.

Comment: This is what I have now : <ComboBox Name="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox" ItemSource={Binding LiniaWyComboBox,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger =PropertyChanged} ToolTip=" "
ToolTipOpening="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox_ToolTipOpening "